# show that if ${a_n} \to a$, and $a>0$, then $\exists N$ such that $a_n>0$ for $n \ge N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Here is the question from my textbook,

> "Suppose that the sequence ${a_n}$ converges to $a$ and that $a>0$. Show that there is an index $N$ such that $a_n>0$ for all indices $n \ge N$"

by the definition of convergent sequence:

because ${a_n} \to a$, for all $\epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n-a| < \epsilon$.

But then I don't know how to proceed. I can figure out the situation (even if it is an oscillating sequence around a), if ${a_n} \to a$, then there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $a_n > 0$.

p.s.: this is the first time I post a question. If there are any unclear/ improvement, please let me know

Comment: It suffices to take $\varepsilon=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $a_n\to a$ and that $a>0$. In particular, since $a/2>0$, there must be some $N$ such that, for $n\ge N$, $a_n$ is within distance $a/2$ of $a$. In symbols,
$$
|a_n-a|<\frac{a}{2}
$$
for all $n\ge N$. This follows from taking $\varepsilon=\frac{a}{2}$ in the definition of convergence.

Now note that
$$
|a_n-a|<\frac{a}{2}\iff -\frac{a}{2}<a_n-a<\frac{a}{2}
$$
The left inequality then gives
$$
\frac{a}{2}<a_n
$$
for all $n\ge N$.